# Image load rendering flashes in Firefox.

Tags: jquery, firefox

On a slow connection the image disappears after it fades in then reappears.

```
$('#image').load(function(){
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

That is basically all I am doing. Works perfect on a fast connection, but on a slow connection the image flashes just after the fade finishes. Any idea on how to fix this? I don't even know where to start.

I have also tried the `waitForImages();` and a few other pluggins. It doesn't seem to be detecting the image load, its some kind of rendering bug.

Comment: I have noticed this happen on a slider plugin before on slow connection. It was either Orbit Slider or BxSlider. 
Have you tried to change the delay > $(this).fadeIn(800); ?

Comment: Maybe useing pure JS not JQuery would help by being faster. (Also would give you more insight into the problem.)

Comment: @miro I will try adjusting the speed.

Comment: Is the image hidden before you bind to it's `.load` event? `.fadeIn()` on a visible element hides the element and then fades it in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).css("display", "none");
$(this).fadeIn();
```

Comment: `display:none;` is set in an external css file. The fade in works, the flash happens right afterward.